# Is there types for MS Edge as there is for Chrome?

Tags: javascript, typescript, microsoft-edge

Google Chrome has [@types/chrome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chrome) for extension developing. Is there same thing for MS Edge? I find some mismatches between chrome and edge browsers and was hoping that types could help a bunch.

Comment: that's odd, I thought edge was a chromium pig with microsoft lipstick - what mismatches have you found?

Comment: `chrome.action.onClicked` for example is not available on Edge.

Comment: `chrome.action` requires manifest version 3 - according to MicroSoft, [browserAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/port-chrome-extension) is supported - perhaps you're doing it wrong - are you setting manifest version as 3?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link above :p should've been [action](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/) and that isn't mentioned in microsoft docs :p

Comment: Yes, but I think running it from built in console is not supposed to work. Perhaps it might be because of permissions that I did not grant, while in extension it will be granted. Like @kwsp said, Chrome types can be used, but have to refer to supported API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it. Edge is based on Chromium, and the same Chromium extension can be submitted to the Edge extension store.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/

> If you've already developed an extension for another Chromium-based browser, you can submit it to the Microsoft Edge Add-ons website. You don't need to rewrite your extension, and must verify it works in Microsoft Edge. When you migrate an existing Chromium extension to other Chromium browsers, make sure the same APIs or alternatives are available for your target browser.

For compatibility, make sure the API you use is supported by Edge ([Supported APIs for Microsoft Edge extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/api-support))

Comment: Please add a quote for the relevant part in addition instead of just posting the link.

Comment: I assume you say Chrome extensions can be used in Edge, thus it's okay to use Chrome provided types? Or there are types for Chromium?

Comment: Yes, just use the [Supported APIs for Microsoft Edge extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/api-support)